CMake doesn't handle headers generation dependency
I'm having a problem with CMake where it doesn't make the source code dependent on the the target which generates headers.
My directory structure looks like this:
Project
   |--- CMakelists.txt [add_subdirectory(src)]
   |--- src
        |--- CMakelists.txt [add_subdirectory(3rdparty), add_subdirectory(wrapper), add_subdirectory(lib1)]
        |--- 3rdparty
               |--- CMakelists.txt
               |--- submodule1
                      |--- FindSubmodule1.cmake
                      |--- script.perl
                      |--- submodule1.cpp
        |--- wrapper
               |--- CMakelists.txt
               |--- wrapper.cpp
               |--- wrapper.h
        |--- lib1
               |--- CMakelists.txt
               |--- lib.c
               |--- lib.h

submodule1 is a git submodule written in C++, wrapper exposes the C++ functions from the submodule as C to I can use them in lib1. So lib.c includes wrapper.h which includes submodule1.h.
Now, submodule1.h is generated using script.perl which is executed from FindSubmodule1.cmake as such:
add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.h
    DEPENDS C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.cpp
    COMMAND perl C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\script.perl
    ARGS C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.cpp C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.h
)

set_source_files_properties(C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.h PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)

When adding a message() in there, I can see that those lines are processed, the paths are right, etc
In order for CMake to understand the dependency and generate build files accordingly, I added a custom target to src/wrapper/CMakelists.txt:
set(WRAPPER_SOURCES
    wrapper.cpp
)

add_library(WRAPPER STATIC
    "${WRAPPER_SOURCES}"
)

add_custom_target(GENERATE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES
    DEPENDS
        C:\xxx\src\3rdparty\submodule1\submodule1.h
)

add_dependencies(WRAPPER
    GENERATE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES
)

But this doesn't seem to be enough. When building with Ninja on MSYS/MinGW64, gcc complains that #include "submodule1.h": no such file or directory and MinGW-make says there's no rule to build GENERATE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES.
I can't see what I did wrong there, as it seems like creating a dependency on a custom target which depends on the header to force the generation should be enough, that's what I've seen in other similar questions around here anyway. Any idea?

In CMake custom commands are local to the directory where they are created. That is, custom target GENERATE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES created in the src/wrapper/CMakelists.txt simply doesn't see the custom command created in src/third_party/CMakeLists.txt. You could move definition of the custom target to the same CMakeLists.txt file which creates custom command; unlike to commands, targets has global visibility.
